# nodejs authorisation by user types (Roles) , allow access based on user type

Tags: node.js, authentication, authorization

Hi I'm new to nodejs and I want to know how to handle role based user accounts in nodejs.

In my application it's having two types of users

1. Vendors
2. Customers

Currently i'm authenticating users using passport and passport-jwt, and it's working perfectly.

So now I want to authorise API routes based on the user type, such as there can be some routes that has to allow access only for vendors .

Can any one help me on this, What is the best way to authorise routes by user type? OR  is there a way to authenticate user token by user type?

Here is my code,

```
router.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
    res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please pass username and password.'});
  } else {
    var newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password
    });
    // save the user
    newUser.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Username already exists.'});
      }
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.'});
    });
  }
});

router.post('/signin', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({
    username: req.body.username
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (!user) {
      res.send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
    } else {
      // check if password matches
      user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (isMatch && !err) {
          // if user is found and password is right create a token
          var token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret);
          // return the information including token as JSON
          res.json({success: true, token: 'JWT ' + token});
        } else {
          res.send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'});
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

router.get('/book', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), function(req, res) {

      res.json("This is it, authorized");

});
```

Thanks